# Microwave oven control board not working

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, voltage-regulator, repair, microwave

I am attaching two pictures of the control board. Can someone explain why the positive output from transformer is going to ground while negative output is going to the voltage regulator. The negative voltage regulator IC code is kia7905 pi.

And how can a microcontroller be powered from a negative rail? The issue is while applying AC no display is turned on, the kia7905pi is probably bad, so I desoldered it. But my main concern is can someone explain how this negative voltage is generated from transformers secondary side and why the negative rail is being used as supply whilst positive one is held at ground? Also, what are those two rectifier diodes you can see in picture doing? Negative rectification?

I want to understand this circuit and kia7905. What alternative IC exist that can be used, as I cant find it online locally. The input to this from the transformer after those rectifier diodes is around -20 V and the input pin is second. And what is a zener diode doing there?[image]

[image]

Comment: Please put spaces only behind punctuation marks, not before them.  This affects readability.

Comment: Darned right it isn't working. What happened [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8FCy.png)?? I think there's more to the story than a failed IC.

Answer (score 1):

From the pictures I assume the schematic looks like this. A negative linear voltage regulator LM7905 is used, not very common, but possible.

It is a bit hard to think upside down. There may be small advantages to have +5 V as GND in very special cases or the engineer came from ancient PNP circuits, where the negative supply often was GND, as it was in the early Volkswagen Beetle with 6 V battery.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8oOx5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: It surely is a 15 years old microwave oven manufactured by a local  electronics appliances company here in Pakistan name as Dawlance

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasHafeez Did this anwer your question?